# What's the easiest way to implement this multi-level drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I want to implement the following system of drop down lists:
[image]

I'm aware that drop down lists are implemented using `<select>` statements. However, I'm not sure if I need to use Javascript commands to handle my requirements listed in the picture. How would you suggest to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have all three drop down on the page but dropdown 2 and 3 will be hidden. On change of first drop down you will have to check the value of first drop down and show second and third dropdown. Demo is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vKJ9G/1/)

In html we define three dropdowns first is visible and second and third are hidden. We will show the hidden dropdown when 3 is selected from first dropdown

```
<select id="sel1" >    
    <option > 1 </option>
    <option > 2 </option>
    <option > 3 </option>
</select>

<select id="sel2" style="display:none" >
    <option > 1 </option>
    <option > 2 </option>
    <option > 3 </option>
</select>

<select id="sel3" style="display:none" >
    <option > 1 </option>
    <option > 2 </option>
    <option > 3 </option>
</select>

​In javascript we have show the hidden dropdowns when 3 is selected from first drop down

$('#sel1').change(function ()
{   
    if($(this).val() == "3")
    {

        $('#sel2').show();
        $('#sel3').show();
    }
}
);
​
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to only allow the user to select second and third options based on the selection event in the first option, you are probably going to need JavaScript to do this. If you have to cater for users with JavaScript disabled you will have to have something like an Update button that posts to the server where server-side code in ASP.Net / PHP / Django / Node.js or something of that sort, builds the second and third options and returns them to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your insights on this design question. I think I'll just tell them to enable Javascript then. No point trying to cater anyone who don't want to set up their systems for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the second and third dropdowns inside `div`s and keep them hidden initially. Once the value of first is selected, make the second visible and so on. You can easily do this with javascript. For eg:

```
function onLoad() {
document.getElementById("dayDropDownDiv").style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

and create the select inside the div in the `body` as:

```
<div id="dayDropDownDiv">
    <label for="select-Day" class="select">Day:</label>
    <select name="select-day" id="dayDropDown" onchange="dayChange(this)"></select>
</div>
```

You can also create the dropdowns programmatically in javascript. You'll have to add the `<option>`s to the `<select>`'s `innerHTML` as:

```
function addValues() {
    var dayOptionsList = "";

for(loopIndex=1;loopIndex<=31;loopIndex++){
        dayOptionsList = dayOptionsList+"<option>"+loopIndex+"</option>";//<-this will create an options list for days
    var daySelector  = document.getElementById("dayDropDown");
    daySelector.innerHTML = dayOptionsList;//done
}
```

Finally, make them visible when the first `<select>`'s particular option is selected:

```
function firstValueSelected( resultsObj){
     var val = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;//<- text of selected option
     if(val=="f")
         document.getElementById("dayDropDownDiv").style.visibility="visible";
}
```